# How to make api call in NuxtJs (vuex) for all routes and pages (spa mode)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I know it is possible to use `nuxtServerInit` when Nuxt is in 'universal' (ssr) mode. but I need to have same functionality in `spa` mode.

I want to use it to call API for getting some settings from backend, so I need to call API  for every route.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [use fetch hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook) or [Async Data](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data) i use fetch and it can be used on any component and called after mount event and can be called manually

Answer (score 0):

easiest I know would be commiting to the store on the layout of your pages.
call your API on mounted cycle in layout and commit the response to vuex store.

The only downside would be having to implement the code in all of your layouts.